# Node: property defined in REPL and undefined in file

Tags: node.js

This works in Node REPL:

```
> globalThis.crypto
{
   // Lots of stuff
}
```

The same does not work in a file:

```
// file.js
console.log(globalThis.crypto);

$ node file.js
undefined
```

The documentation states it should work:

> Use globalThis.crypto or require('node:crypto').webcrypto to access this module.
> https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#web-crypto-api

What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce; it works fine for me. What Node version?

Comment: @code v18.15.0 (latest LTS: Hydrogen)

Answer (score 2):

In v19 (to which the documentation corresponds), both forms work.

In v18, the docs state: `Use require('node:crypto').webcrypto to access this module`.

Furthermore, the docs for the REPL state: `The default evaluator will automatically load Node.js core modules into the REPL environment when used.`